# How to fill background colour with fixed sized grid

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to layout a 4x4 grid, with text in the centre of each, and a filled background colour, and I can't get the background colour to expand to fill the whole grid square.

This is the UI code:

```
  body: new Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            new Column(
              children: [
                new Container(
                  color: Colors.pink,
                  child: new Text("Column 1a"),
                )
              ],
            ),
            new Column(
              children: [
                new Text("Column 1b"),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            new Column(
              children: [
                new Text("Column 2a"),
              ],
            ),
            new Column(
              children: [
                new Text("Column 2b"),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ]),
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]

Note: I've tried using Flexible and Expanded to replace Container, but I get an exception:

*The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The thing is, you're using `spaceEvenly` as alignment and never forces your cells to take the space possible.

So in the end, your cells take the least amount of space possible => Here, just the size of your text.

You'd have to play with `Expanded` to fix it. Which I *could* help you with. But I won't ! **[evil laughs]**

---

In your case, there's a much, MUCH easier way to achieve the desired effect. That is `GridView`.

With `GridView` you can specify a `gridDelegate` to have some unique grid rules. One existing `gridDelegate` is `SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount` which ensure that there's a fixed number of columns ; cells will have for width `width / columnCount` ; and have a custom width/height ratio.

In your case, you want 2 columns and the ratio to be `availableWidth / availableHeight` so that 4 cells fills the screen, but without overflow.

Now you're asking : *Cool, but how do I get `availableWidth / availableHeight` ?*

The answer : `LayoutBuilder`.

Layout builder basically delegates the rendering to a callback that takes a `Constraints` as argument. Where that constraint contains the minimum/maximum width/height the widget can have.

=> `availableWidth / availableHeight` will be `constaint.maxWidth / constaint.maxHeight`.

The end result will be much more concise and readable ; with the bonus of being easily customizable (change column count, add less/more then 4 cells, ...)

```
new LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constaint) {
    return new GridView(
      gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        childAspectRatio: constaint.maxWidth / constaint.maxHeight,
      ),
      children: <Widget>[
        new Container(color: Colors.red, child: new Center(child: new Text("data"))),
        new Container(color: Colors.purple, child: new Center(child: new Text("data"))),
        new Container(color: Colors.yellow, child: new Center(child: new Text("data"))),
        new Container(color: Colors.green, child: new Center(child: new Text("data"))),
      ],
    );
  },
),
```

[image]

Comment: That's just what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Your gridView widget is inside a scaffold.
The Scaffold has a body.
Define a color for that body.

```
return Scaffold :
  appBar...
  body : Container (color : Colors.yellow , child : nameGridViewWidget () )
```